# How to feed vector to functions from math module (python)

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np
import math
```

given a list of functions e.g. [lambda x: x ** 2, lambda x: x - 5, math.sin, math.cos]
and x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 20)
I wanted to calculate the y values of x for each of the function in the list

I tried with the code:

```
def exe_function(x, funcs):
    y = []
    for func in funcs:
        y.append(func(x))
    return np.array(y)
```

It should return a len(funcs) by len(x) numpy array

When I only run with the first two functions it works fine, but everytime when I tried to work with math.sin and math.cos, error would occur:

> TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

why is that and how can I fix that?

**(it is required that the input from math module should be math., so I can't change it from there)**

Comment: What result do you hope for when you do `math.sin(numpy.linspace(-10, 10, 20) )`?

Comment: Perhaps you want to use `numpy.vectorize(math.sin)` in your list of functions rather than `math.sin`? Also, in this specific example, `numpy` has a version of these `math` methods you can directly use.

Comment: error is clear, `math.sin / cos` expect just one value , you need to use numpy  `np.sin` / `np.cos` to work with arrays

Comment: @eshirvana but the input requires it to be from math. (it's a default automatic input, the sin and cos functions would only be from the math module) So how what can I do from this point?

Comment: @FliegendeButter then you have to modify your function to handle these cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for all the answers and sorry for the bad description of the question.

So I found out (through your help) that I mainly want to fix the problem of not being able to give vector argument to a math function. The problem was I couldn't change where the functions come from, they have to be from **math** so I can't really use numpy functions.

A fix to this is vectorize the imported function from math using

```
np.vectorize(math.sin)
```

So instead of

```
def exe_function(x, funcs):
y = []
for func in funcs:
    y.append(func(x))
return np.array(y)
```

I could verctorize all the functions in the list even if it could take vectors as input:

```
def exe_function(x, funcs):
y = []

for func in funcs:
vfunc = np.vectorize(func)
    y.append(func(x))
return np.array(y)
```

and depending on the wished form of the end result the y could be transposed

Answer (score 1):

math.sin and math.cos operate on scalars not arrays. Use the Numpy versions which do operate on arrays:

```
 [lambda x: x ** 2, lambda x: x - 5, np.sin, np.cos]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only pass one value at a time in `math.sin` and `math.cos` functions, whereas you're passing an array of 20 values at once, which is causing the issue.

You can create a lambda function for `math.sin` and `math.cos` as well, to calculate sine and cosine individually for each value in the array.

```
import numpy as np
import math

def exe_function(x, funcs):
    y = []
    for func in funcs:
        y.append(func(x))
    return np.array(y)

results = exe_function(np.linspace(-10, 10, 20), [lambda x: x ** 2, lambda x: x - 5, lambda x: [math.sin(val) for val in x], lambda x: [math.cos(val) for val in x]])
print(results)
```

I replicated your code and updated sine and cosine functions with lambda and got the following output.

```
[[ 1.00000000e+02  8.00554017e+01  6.23268698e+01  4.68144044e+01
   3.35180055e+01  2.24376731e+01  1.35734072e+01  6.92520776e+00
   2.49307479e+00  2.77008310e-01  2.77008310e-01  2.49307479e+00
   6.92520776e+00  1.35734072e+01  2.24376731e+01  3.35180055e+01
   4.68144044e+01  6.23268698e+01  8.00554017e+01  1.00000000e+02]
 [-1.50000000e+01 -1.39473684e+01 -1.28947368e+01 -1.18421053e+01
  -1.07894737e+01 -9.73684211e+00 -8.68421053e+00 -7.63157895e+00
  -6.57894737e+00 -5.52631579e+00 -4.47368421e+00 -3.42105263e+00
  -2.36842105e+00 -1.31578947e+00 -2.63157895e-01  7.89473684e-01
   1.84210526e+00  2.89473684e+00  3.94736842e+00  5.00000000e+00]
 [ 5.44021111e-01 -4.59479904e-01 -9.99169621e-01 -5.30270815e-01
   4.73897526e-01  9.99701037e-01  5.16379600e-01 -4.88189209e-01
  -9.99966780e-01 -5.02351155e-01  5.02351155e-01  9.99966780e-01
   4.88189209e-01 -5.16379600e-01 -9.99701037e-01 -4.73897526e-01
   5.30270815e-01  9.99169621e-01  4.59479904e-01 -5.44021111e-01]
 [-8.39071529e-01 -8.88188166e-01 -4.07439268e-02  8.47828321e-01
   8.80579999e-01  2.44506880e-02 -8.56359801e-01 -8.72737816e-01
  -8.15095137e-03  8.64663702e-01  8.64663702e-01 -8.15095137e-03
  -8.72737816e-01 -8.56359801e-01  2.44506880e-02  8.80579999e-01
   8.47828321e-01 -4.07439268e-02 -8.88188166e-01 -8.39071529e-01]]
```